# Why is played sound distorted in R with package audio?

Tags: r, audio, package, wav, playback

I have quite some experience in coding in R, however I am fairly new to using audio processing methods in R.
To play a wav-file in R, I have found multiple packages that could help me (tuneR, audio, signal, seewaveIO). Because the package audio has some methods that I also need to use, I want to use audio::play to play the wav-file that I uploaded. However, when I play a wav-file with audio::play, it does not sound at all like the original wav-file. I have tried using the play method of the beforementioned packages as well, but I have the same problem there. I tried using different rates, but nothing sounds like it should sound.

I know this is not reproducible code, but I do the following:

```
audioFile <- load.wave(*path to wav file*)
audio::play(audioFile)
```

`audioFile$rate` gives me a rate of 11025. So I have also tried using `audio::play(audioFile, 11025)` or `audio::play(audioFile, 22050)`.

What am I doing wrong?